# GREP/GAWK If .txt file contains string copy file

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin, gawk, gnuwin32

okay so i know of grep -rhi, which extrats the line if string is found, but I want to copy the entire file so for example,

file.txt >

```
 isexample #new
 iesameplxpele
 ieamama #new
```

now if I used grep -rhi "#new", it would extract only

```
isexample #new
ieamama #new
```

where as I want all the contents within the file including

```
iesameplxpele
```

How would I do this?

Of course the .txt file must contain #new in either one of its lines.

Comment: maybe something like `if grep -q "search string" file ; then cat file ; fi` ? Good luck.

Comment: The `gawk` tag is visited by far fewer people far less often than the `awk` tag so to get more people looking at your question with a view to helping you, tag your awk questions with `awk`, optionally add a `gawk` tag if you like, and state in your question that you're using gawk.